# Univocity Parsers, "Cannot resolve method writeValue(int)"?

Tags: java, csv

Univocity Parsers, "Cannot resolve method writeValue(int)" appears with the following code, opened in IntelliJ, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
public void write(){

        // Writing to an in-memory byte array. This will be printed out to the standard output so you can easily see the result.
        ByteArrayOutputStream csvResult = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // CsvWriter (and all other file writers) work with an instance of java.io.Writer
        Writer outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(csvResult);

        TsvWriter writer = new TsvWriter(outputWriter, new TsvWriterSettings());

        writer.writeHeaders("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");

        //writes a value to the first column
        writer.writeValue(10);

        //writes a value to the second column
        writer.writeValue(20);

        //writes a value to the fourth column (index 3 represents the 4th column - the one with header "D")
        writer.writeValue(3, 40);

        //overrides the value in the first column. "A" indicates the header name.
        writer.writeValue("A", 100.0);

        //flushes all values to the output, creating a row.
        writer.writeValuesToRow();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you got this sample from an example built using the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT version. Update your `pom.xml` to use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

You might also need to add the following to your `pom.xml` in to enable maven to pick up snapshot builds:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

If you don't use maven you can just go to the following url directly: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Finally, this example was taken from a snapshot version and the method you are after has been renamed to `addValue`. Check the examples [here](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/test/java/com/univocity/parsers/examples/WriterExamples.java#L283).

Comment: Hmm, adding univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20151116.050805-20.jar from that link to the project's library, IntelliJ still doesn't resolve the `writeValue` in this statement `writer.writeValue(10);`

Comment: You got an old snapshot. Scroll to the bottom of the page to grab the latest: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20160115.024244-24.jar

Comment: Hmm, this link `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20160115.024244-24.jar` generates a 404, is there a working link?, thanks.

Comment: That's because the folder contains snapshots! They get replaced over time. Just scroll to the bottom of the page. Check the latest dates and get the latest build.

Comment: I’ve added the .jar `univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20160119.000236-29.jar` to the `/lib` folder of the IntelliJ project, however, even after `IntelliJ > Invalidate Caches / Restart`,  `writeValue` is viewed by IntelliJ as `"Cannot resolve method writeValue(int)"`.

Comment: So it seems a like a problem with intellij that's not updating the dependencies

Comment: IntelliJ updates all the other dependencies perfectly, why would it be just Univocity Parsers that is not being updated?

Comment: Try using maven instead to se if it helps. You can also clone the source code from github and see for yourself that the methods are there.

Comment: Also copying the jar into the lib folder is not enough. You'd need to at least  reference it in the project settings as well.

Comment: Looking in both the `CsvWriter.class` and `AbstractWriter.class`  of `univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20160119.000236-29.jar `, I cant find any method named `writeValue(`), where exactly is that method located within `univocity-parsers-2.0.0-20160119.000236-29.jar `?

Comment: Ha, it was renamed to "addValue". Check the examples [here](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/test/java/com/univocity/parsers/examples/WriterExamples.java)